# Selenium set date to Calendar

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I need to set Date to calendar. There are field with calendar icon:

- http://prntscr.com/7swv0r

---

and html code:

- http://prntscr.com/7swvny

---

and full xpath to this element:

```
html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/input
```

Comment: First click on Calender input field. That will display calender dialog, inspect particular date. and write xpath for that element. Or else you post HTML code of that calender.

Comment: All ID's is dynamic, so I should use just xpath, but I have exception that I can't find element with this xpath:

-- //table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/input

Comment: Use text() instead of ID's or className's.

Comment: but I don't have text on this field

Comment: I can't click and open calendar

Comment: Is it possible to open calender directly in website after clicking on input field? I think its possible for sure. Can you post your URL..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83309/discussion-between-saritha-g-and-vitaliy-mckay).

Comment: I think that date's text is there in between tag 'a'. Once check it.

Answer (score 0):

Did it with full Xpath..

```
session.getPage().clickButtonByXpath("//body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/div[2]/form/div[4]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/input");
            session.getPage().clickLinkByXpath("//a[text()='30']");
```